# Consider the following circuit system (RLC Circuit, R and L parallel then series with C), please determine the transfer function

Tags: circuit-analysis, control-system, transfer-function, passive-networks

i'm trying to figure this out, but i'm still confused. Can anyone help me? Thank you

[image]

This is what i've done. Am i in the correct path?
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Looks like homework. Show us what you've done & where you're stuck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, i've sent what i''ve done, is that correct?

Comment: (This question has been reopened, now that the OP has added their own work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your transfer function is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}+\left(\text{R}\space\text{||}\space\text{sL}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{sL}}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{sL}+\text{s}^2\text{CLR}}\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

Comment: oke thank you for your response